# How can I get jquery to clear a table cell?

Tags: jquery

My table looks like this:[image: my table]

How can I get jquery to remove the dropdown or clear the contents from the last cell if my first cell has a value in it? The dropdown should only appear if the first two cells are blank.

```
<table>
<tr>headings here</tr>
<tr>
 <td>name</td>
 <td>id</td>
 <td>other id</td>
 <td>status</td>
 <td>select location</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>name</td>
 <td>id</td>
 <td>other id</td>
 <td>status</td>
 <td>select location</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>name</td>
 <td>id</td>
 <td>other id</td>
 <td>status</td>
 <td>select location</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

Got it. I needed a trim().

http://jsfiddle.net/RN5Dn/1/

Comment: can you post some html that can depict the scenario...

Comment: by cell you mean last `td` of last `tr` or the last `tr`?

Comment: @3nigma Added more HTML code that's more like my scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that your table looks like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>soon it will fade away</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Samurai</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

you can do this

```
$(function(){
    if(!$("table tr:first").find("td:first").text())
    {
        $("table tr:last").delay('1000').fadeOut("slow");
    }
});
```

you can remove the dropdown by selecting it and then removing it by using `remove` like

```
$("#idOfYourDropDown").remove();
```

here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/uF7M5/4/

in the fiddle i have used `delay` so that the value remains visible for a bit of time

[`jquery :first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

[`jquery :last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)

**EDIT**

i am assuming that if there is no name you want to hide/remove the `select location`

```
$(function(){

$("table tr").each(function(){

    if(!$("td:first",this).text())
    {
        $("td:last",this).delay("1000").fadeOut("slow");
    }

});

});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/uF7M5/3/

Comment: This almost worked for me. I added more html to you can see my scenario. Please edit. Thanks!

Comment: @Trey Copeland: what do you want to do ?

Comment: I want to clear out the dropdown on only the row that has an empty first cell/td.

Comment: it's still removing all dropdowns from every row. I added an edit to your code to show you what im working with now. any other ideas?

Comment: its not removing from all rows only the rows that have the first cell empty

Comment: the second row's drop down is still intact... and where you have edited the code can you share a fiddle?

Comment: i have added the fiddle in my original question. I needed a trim().

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty http://jsfiddle.net/nTExe/

```
$("tr:gt(0)").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find("td:eq(0)").html().length > 0 && $(this).find("td:eq(1)").html().length > 0) {
        $(this).find("td:last").html("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just hide it with a CSS property or something, then show it again when necessary. If you want, you can manage a hidden input value that indicates whether the dropdown is visible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just put an id to your table (e.g. id="tbl") and then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tbl tr').each(function(i) {
        if (i === 0) return; // skip header row
        var children = $(this).children();
        var tdVal1 = children.eq(0).text();
        var tdVal2 = children.eq(1).text();
        if (tdVal1 || tdVal2) {
            children.eq(-1).html('');
        }
    });
});
```

You can test it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/protron/8AfVN/3/

Comment: Your code clears out all the Dropdowns from every row for me. I added more html for my scenario please take a look.

Comment: I just made a change to skip the first row as that is the header row. Please test it again.

Comment: this code still removes every dropdown from the last <td> in every <tr>. it should only remove the last <td> if the first <td> in that row is empty.

Comment: Only the first td should be empty? in the question you said: `The dropdown should only appear if the first two cells are blank`. But you can change the condition of `if (tdVal1 || tdVal2) {` to `if (!tdVal1) {` in order to remove the last when the first is empty.